# how to change the color of text in Recyclerview by condition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[XML Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4D9Y.jpg)i have data in recyclerview like date, description and status getting from server.i wanna change the color of status if i get a string as Received or Pending

[Fetching Data From Server through Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSTO0.jpg)

[Output Screen of My RecyclerView Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI6l5.png)
[OrderAdapter a piece of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7S9u.jpg)

Comment: how you can fetch data from server ? share piece of codes

Comment: Through Json and request a server through volley

Comment: share your recycler view adapter code how you are currently setting the text

Comment: You can check image description there....Everything is fine...Code Everything is working

Comment: @ShubhamRaitka  Code is working,Also Getting data from Server but i wanna to change the text in RecyclerView after getting data from server not from xml text Color

Comment: @ShubhamRaitka now Check the image above i add as Output Screen of My RecyclerView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your adapter wherever you set your status text, you can do the following:

```
String status = mycontact.get(position).getDelivery_status();

if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Received")){
    myholder.txt_status.setText("Received");
    myholder.txt_status.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5CC615"));
}else{
    myholder.txt_status.setText("Pending");
    myholder.txt_status.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
}
```

Comment: @M Ali Khattak, does this answer solved your problem?

Comment: Working on it but you can check another pic above which is order adapter binding method code

Comment: So, you are able to change the list item's background color and you are just facing the issue with the status text color change, right?

Comment: ...Thanks buddy

Comment: No problem brother. You can upvote the answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a **color** for all `recyclerview` items by **default** like **RED**

So in `Adapater` you can change **adapted items** background color to **GREEN** one by one .

Comment: I wanna to change the color through condition that if status is pending then set text color Red else Green

Comment: then  first you must update your question 
second you can do same action inside `adapter` when `adapting` started you can change color and again when finished